# Mavericks frequently doesn't resolve any hosts after router switch; pings fine

Tags: macos, network, dns

After a switch to a new router, I frequently experience that all sites fail to resolve under Mavericks 10.9.4 on MBA mid-2011, both with Safari, Chrome and pinging google.com. It lasts for variable time, from few seconds to several minutes. Same for wifi and Ethernet.

However, during such outages:

- repeated pings to 8.8.8.8 works fine from OS X Terminal
- sites open fine in Windows under Parallels if network is set as "Bridged", doesn't work when network is set to "Shared"
- another Mac (MBP 2010) with OS X Mountain Lion <strike>resolves and opens sites just without a problem (checked by a script repeatedly pinging google.com)</strike> has the same problem as MBA
- iPhone connected to the same wifi resolves and opens sites just fine

Switching back to my original router seems to solve the problem.

How to debug and resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out the root cause was problematic new router (Sercomm RV6688BCM in my case). After Internet provider replaced it with another instance of the same product, the problem resolved itself.